# Add Sortby Titles Like "Name", "Size" to TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a tree view that loads the information from a directory. What I want to do is simply add a titles to the top of the `treeview`. How would I do this? Or should I use a diffrent control?

Example:
[image]

Comment: maybe use a custom `ListView` instead.

Comment: Can a `ListView` load my directory as a `Tree`?

Comment: a custom `ListView` can replace a `TreeView`. However I see that your `TreeView` has some columns, it looks like that it's not a standard `TreeView`?

Comment: We got an assignment requesting a form that looks like the image. That's why I though maybe a different control is being used in the preview as it combines elements of both a `TreeView` and `ListView`.

Comment: have you tried searching for `multi-column treeview`, even there are some custom `DataGridView` displaying the content in `Tree` like as a TreeView does. `codeproject` is where I've found such demos, they would be what you want.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it. [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23746/TreeView-with-Columns] seems to have what I am looking for.